# How to view custom log files using Log Viewer in Laravel

Tags: laravel, logging

I am using [Laravel Log Reader](https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-log-reader)

for viewing log files. It works fine.
But I also have other log files, how can I view them usig this viewer?

Comment: can mention custom log path and format of filename.

Comment: @JohnLobo Like I have created a separate log file if any user comes to a 404 page. It creates log of the URLs visited by the user in '404log.log' in storage/logs/ path.

Comment: by default that package doesnt support becuase it reads 'logs/laravel-*.log' this format

Comment: @JohnLobo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989579/how-to-store-the-ip-with-the-error-logs-reported-in-laravel Please answer if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package matching specific file pattern `logs/laravel-*.log` .So your mentioned log file doesn't match. This package doesn't have configuration to change it at present. But still if you want to view your own log files then you can override method and create your own view file.

I can provide you some basic idea and make sure i haven't written code in super clean.This is to get some idea

Custom class which is extended

```
<?php


namespace App\Helper;


class LaravelLogReader extends \Haruncpi\LaravelLogReader\LaravelLogReader
{



    public function getLogFileDates()
    {
        $dates = [];
        $files = glob(storage_path('logs/*.log'));

        $files = array_reverse($files);
        foreach ($files as $path) {
            $fileName = basename($path);



            array_push($dates, $fileName);
        }

        return $dates;
    }


    public function get()
    {

        $availableDates = $this->getLogFileDates();

        if (count($availableDates) == 0) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'No log available'
            ]);
        }

        $configDate = $this->config['date'];
        if ($configDate == null) {
            $configDate = $availableDates[0];
        }

        if (!in_array($configDate, $availableDates)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'No log file found with selected date ' . $configDate
            ]);
        }


        $pattern = "/^\[(?<date>.*)\]\s(?<env>\w+)\.(?<type>\w+):(?<message>.*)/m";

        $fileName =  $configDate;
        $content = file_get_contents(storage_path('logs/' . $fileName));
        preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

        $logs = [];
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $logs[] = [
                'timestamp' => $match['date'],
                'env' => $match['env'],
                'type' => $match['type'],
                'message' => trim($match['message'])
            ];
        }


        $date = $fileName;

        $data = [
            'available_log_dates' => $availableDates,
            'date' => $date,
            'filename' => $fileName,
            'logs' => $logs
        ];

        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data' => $data]);
    }


}
```

and view file which is copied from library view .i have named it as `log.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Log Reader</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var angularUrl = '{{asset('laravel-log-reader/angular.min.js')}}';
        window.angular || document.write('<script src="' + angularUrl + '">\x3C/script>')
    </script>


    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #f4f4f4;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .btn {
            text-decoration: none;
            background: antiquewhite;
            padding: 5px 12px;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        header {
            min-height: 30px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 15px;
            background: #3F51B5;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        }
        header .btn_clear_all {
            background: #de4f4f;
            color: #fff;
        }
        header .name {
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: white;
        }

        .content {
            margin-top: 65px;
            padding: 15px;
            background: #fff;
            min-height: 100px;
        }

        .content .date_selector {
            min-height: 26px;
            min-width: 130px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .top_content {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .top_content .top_content_left {
            display: flex;
        }

        .top_content .top_content_left .log_filter {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        .top_content .top_content_left .log_filter .log_type_item {
            margin-right: 4px;
            background: #eae9e9;
            max-height: 20px;
            font-size: 11px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 4px 6px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .top_content .top_content_left .log_filter .log_type_item.active {
            background: #2f2e2f;
            color: white;
        }

        .top_content .top_content_left .log_filter .log_type_item.clear {
            background: #607D8B;
            color: white;
        }

        table {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        table tr {
            border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        table tr:hover {
            background: #f4f4f4;
        }
        thead tr td {
            background: #717171;
            color: #fff;
        }

        table th,
        table td {
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #666;
        }

        table th {
            font-size: 14px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            .top_content {
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .top_content .top_content_left {
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .top_content .log_filter {
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            .top_content .log_filter .log_type_item {
                margin-bottom: 3px;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            header {
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            header .name {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .content {
                margin-top: 90px;
            }

            .btn {
                font-size: 13px;
            }

            .dt_box,
            .selected_date {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .responsive_table {
                max-width: 100%;
                overflow-x: auto;
            }

            table {
                border: 0;
            }

            table thead {
                display: none;
            }

            table tr {
                border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            table td {
                border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
                display: block;
                font-size: 15px;
            }

            table td:last-child {
                border-bottom: 0;
            }

            table td:before {
                content: attr(data-label);
                float: left;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
        }

        .badge {
            padding: 2px 8px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
            -moz-border-radius: 25px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .badge.info {
            background: #6bb5b5;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .badge.warning {
            background: #f7be57;
        }

        .badge.critical {
            background: #de4f4f;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .badge.emergency {
            background: #ff6060;
            color: white;
        }

        .badge.notice {
            background: bisque;
        }

        .badge.debug {
            background: #8e8c8c;
            color: white;
        }

        .badge.alert {
            background: #4ba4ea;
            color: white;
        }

        .badge.error {
            background: #c36a6a;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body ng-controller="LogCtrl">
<header>
    <div class="name">@{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="actions">
        <a class="btn btn_clear_all" href="#" ng-click="clearAll()">Clear All</a>
        <a class="btn" href="{{url(config('laravel-log-reader.admin_panel_path'))}}">Goto Admin Panel</a>
        <a class="btn" href="https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-log-reader" title="Laravel Log Reader">Doc</a>
    </div>
</header>
<section class="content">
    <div class="top_content">
        <div class="top_content_left">
            <div>
                <p class="selected_date" style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>
                        <span ng-show="response.success">Showing Logs: @{{data.date}}</span>
                        <span ng-hide="response.success">@{{response.message}}</span>
                    </strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="log_filter">
                <div class="log_type_item" ng-class="selectedType==tp?'active':''"
                     ng-repeat="tp in logTypes track by $index"
                     ng-click="filterByType(tp)">@{{ tp }}
                </div>
                <div class="log_type_item clear" ng-show="selectedType" ng-click="selectedType=undefined">CLEAR FILTER
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="top_content_right">
            <p class="dt_box">Select Date: <select class="date_selector" ng-model="selectedDate"
                                                   ng-change="init(selectedDate)">
                    <option ng-repeat="dt in data.available_log_dates"
                            value="@{{ dt }}">@{{ dt }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="responsive_table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td width="140">Timestamp</td>
                    <td width="120">Env</td>
                    <td width="120">Type</td>
                    <td>Message</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr ng-repeat="log in data.logs |filter: selectedType track by $index">
                    <td>@{{ log.timestamp }}</td>
                    <td>@{{log.env}}</td>
                    <td><span class="badge @{{ log.type.toLowerCase() }}">@{{ log.type }}</span></td>
                    <td>@{{ log.message }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.controller("LogCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.title = "Log Reader";
            $scope.selectedType = undefined;
            $scope.logTypes = ['INFO', 'EMERGENCY', 'CRITICAL', 'ALERT', 'ERROR', 'WARNING', 'NOTICE', 'DEBUG'];
            var originalData = null;

            $scope.init = function (date) {
                var url = '';
                if (date !== '' && date !== undefined) {
                    url = '{{url(config('laravel-log-reader.api_route_path'))}}?date=' + date
                } else {
                    url = '{{url("custom-logger")}}'
                }
alert(url);
                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.response = data;
                        $scope.data = data.data;
                        originalData = data.data;
                    })
            };

            $scope.init();

            $scope.filterByType = function (tp) {
                $scope.selectedType = tp
            };

            $scope.clearAll = function () {
                if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    var url = '{{url(config('laravel-log-reader.view_route_path'))}}'
                    $http.post(url, {'clear': true})
                        .success(function (data) {
                            if (data.success) {
                                alert(data.message);
                                $scope.init();
                            }
                        })
                }
            }

        })
    </script>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

And add two routes

```
Route::get('custom-logger', function () {

    $laravelLogReader=new \App\Helper\LaravelLogReader();
    return $laravelLogReader->get();

});

Route::get('/log-viewer', function () {

 
    return view('log');
});
```

**Note:** this not fully optimized code but you can write it in better way.This is only to show you can override the package

Another package you can use
Ref:https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer

This package will read all log files and i have tested it it works fine