# How to store the IP with the error logs reported in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I usually get logs of 404 errors URLs, for some reason, I also want to store the IP of the user who visited the URL which will throw 404.
Please help.
This is the code I am using in Exceptions/handler.php

```
 public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{

    if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException ||
        $exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException ||
        $exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){
        $error = [
            'url'    => $request->url(),
        ];

        $message = '404: ' . $error['url'] . "\n" . json_encode($error, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        \Log::channel('404logfile')->debug($message);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: whats the issue of current code ?

Comment: @JohnLobo There is no issue in current code, but I want IP address of the visitor as well with the log being created. Sp how can I code that IP of the visitor with log is created

Answer (score 1):

From Request you can get client ip as well as full url of which user tried to access

To get Full url

```
$request->fullUrl()  or request()->fullUrl()
```

To get ip

```
$request->getClientIp()  or request()->getClientIp()
```

Aslo you can use

```
$request->ip() or request()->ip()
```